# Flex Ant: Compile multiple module

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I am trying to compile my project by using Ant.
I did. But I have some problem. I don't know how to resolve.

```
<!-- Compile Modules (S) -->
<target name="compileModules" depends="compileBLP">
    <record name="${LOG_DIR}/LOG_${CURR_TIME_SUBFIX}${LOG_FILE_TYPE}" append="false" action="start" />
    <cpmdl file="com/dou/pi/views/dm/Module1" />
    <cpmdl file="com/dou/pi/views/pim/Module2" />
    <record name="${LOG_DIR}/LOG_${CURR_TIME_SUBFIX}${LOG_FILE_TYPE}" action="stop" />
</target>
<!-- Compile Modules (E) -->

<macrodef name="cpmdl">
    <attribute name="file" />
    <sequential>
        <echo>@{file}</echo>
        <mxmlc file="${SRC_DIR}/@{file}.mxml" output='${DEPLOY_DIR}/@{file}.swf' optimize="true" debug="false" incremental="false" fork="true">
            <compiler.source-path path-element="${SRC_DIR}" />
            <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" />
            <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
                <include name="libs" />
            </compiler.library-path>
            <compiler.library-path dir="${basedir}" append="true">
                <include name="libs" />
                <include name="src/assets/swc" />
            </compiler.library-path>
            <source-path path-element="${SRC_DIR}" />
        </mxmlc>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

You can see. If I compile 2 modules, I have to load file config 2 times.

```
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
[mxmlc] D:\Projects\BLP\BUILD\DEPLOY\com\dou\pi\views\dm\Module1.swf (1233413 bytes)
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
[mxmlc] D:\Projects\BLP\BUILD\DEPLOY\com\dou\pi\views\pim\Module2.swf (963045 bytes)
```

Maybe, that is not good.
I though, can we load it just 1 time?

Hope you can give me any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing to be done here.  The loading of the config file is done internally by mxmlc, not ant.  Remember, each time you call mxmlc in your ant script, it's launching a new instance of it, so each instance has to load the configuration for itself.

It's similar to how, if you launch your web browser, close it, and reopen it, you'll end up loading your homepage twice.  There's nothing in the environment that can save the page to memory to pass it in to the second invocation of the program.